# Problems with sqlite3 and python - update values in table

Tags: python, sqlite

newbie to programming here.

I am trying to build my own program and what I am trying to do is to update a table (pairs) that already exists with an update in the values.there are three columns: x, y and z which are all integer.

So if I have a and b then I update z with the value I have in test.

```
    mycommand = "UPDATE pairs VALUES (?) WHERE x == a and y == b"
    db2.execute(mycommand)
    db2.commit()
```

what exactly am I doing wrong?
thanks

I get this error when I launch:

> ```
>    "db2.execute(mycommand) sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUE": syntax error"
> ```

the output is supposed to be updating the table value for the rows that contain the original two values. 
If for example the values for x is 5 any y is 10 and z is supposed to change to 50
the value 50 I get from another part of the progam

Comment: It seems like you are not familiar with the UPDATE statement:http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/

Answer (score 0):

resolved using that site and some others. it comes out differently and now works:

```
    mycommand = "UPDATE pairs SET z = 0 WHERE x= {} and y= {}".format(a,b)
```

thanks